# Resetting server admin password in Azure portal breaks deployed app

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-sql-database, connection-string, admin

I reset the Server Admin password in the Azure Portal and it causes connections to fail.

I set up a new login and user in SqlServer to connect to an authentication database (I'm using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity) and changed the connection string to use this new user. This connection worked on my local machine, so I published the app. The connection was still good in the deployed app. I then reset the Server Admin password and within minutes all connections were failing on the deployed app. Is there another location in the portal that I need to change settings, or perhaps in my application code, so that connections don't fail?

I've tried changing the connection strings in the app service configuration settings on Azure Portal, with no effect.

Comment: If you reset the Server Admin password, the SQL database connection string also changed,  you need to get the new connection string or replace the username and password with your new password in old connection string. please try again.

Answer (score 0):

If you reset the Server Admin password, the SQL database connection string also changed, you need to get the new connection string or replace the username and password with your new password in old connection string. please try again.

Rest admin password:

[image]

Connection string:
[image]

Replace the `{your_username}` and `{your_password}` with new admin password in old app connection string, your connection string should like this:

```
Server=tcp:***.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=db_name;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=username;Password=new_admin_password;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Leon, but this doesn't fix the problem. The new connection string is in the app, but it still crashes after about 10 minutes.

Comment: Sorry, I'll find it tonight

Comment: No, my apologies. It's telling me it can't connect to the server admin.

Comment: @mjf First, please test if you can connect to the Azure SQL database with SeverAdmin and new PSD in SSMS. Second, please make sure you have follow the correct step to create new login and user and the user has the right to access the database. You can reference the document [Login and User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins).

Comment: Hi  @mjf ,If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.